# How to slice an input value?

Tags: php, html

My input value is just like this: `Oppa/upload/default.jpeg`

I want to slice the value of an input according by `/` cause i want to get the image file name. Does anyone know some tricks to do this?

example: i want to get `default.png`

```
<input type="text" value="Oppa/upload/default.png" id="fileLink" name="fileLink" />
```

Comment: Seriously! You've never come across PHP's [explode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function before?

Comment: If you don't validate this properly on the backend you could cause yourself a world of troubles. That being said, you're probably looking for explode().

Comment: Why the Javascript and jQuery tags?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am supposing that if your image path will not be change from `Oppa/upload/` than this Should work using [explode](http://php.net/explode) :

```
$str = "Oppa/upload/default.jpeg";
$s= explode("Oppa/upload/",$str);
echo $s[1];
```

Another Best thing you can do with defining the relative path as a constant, so :

```
const path = "Oppa/upload/";
$str = "Oppa/upload/default.jpeg";
$s= explode(path,$str);
echo $s[1];
```

will also work.

Comment: reason for down vote ?

Comment: I was wandering the same? +1 from me

Comment: please give reason if you are going with down vote, so that i can find my self where i am wrong for this solution.

Comment: re-invents the wheel and hard-codes the file path - ergo: not useful.

Comment: than there is another solution with `const` , just change at 1 place and will work everywhere.

Answer (score 3):

Use `basename()`:

```
$path = "Oppa/upload/default.jpeg";
echo basename($path); //will output "default.jpeg"
echo basename($path, '.jpeg'); //will output "default"
```

The first parameter is the path of which the trailing component will be removed. If the first parameter ends in the optional second parameter, the second parameter will also be cut off.

> On Windows, both slash (/) and backslash (\) are used as directory
>   separator character. In other environments, it is the forward slash
>   (/).
>    - [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php)

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`basename()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) PHP function.

Answer (score 1):

This will work for you

```
$path = "Oppa/upload/default.jpeg";
echo basename($path);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [pathinfo() php function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php)

```
$path = "http://domain.tld/Oppa/upload/default.png";
$info = pathinfo ( $path, PATHINFO_BASENAME ); // returns default.png
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution, using `preg_match()`

```
<?php
$path = "http://domain.tld/Oppa/upload/default.png";   // or "C:\\domain.tld\Oppa\upload\default.jpg";
$pattern = '/[\/|\\\\]((?:.(?!\/|\\\\))+)$/';
if(preg_match($pattern, $path, $matches)){
    echo $matches[1];  // default.png or default.jpg
}
?>
```

Note: People claim to have problems using `basename()` with asian characters